# Need to ignore the element value for the full set of Body element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to ignore the element for particular instance for the full set of Body element,

My Input xml is:

```
<Body>
<p> </p>
<h1>Taking</h1>
<p>Your records.</p>
<h2>Blood Pressure?</h2>
<p>mmm.</p>
</Body>
```

XSL I used as:

```
<xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
         <topic>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
            <title>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </title>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::h2">
                     <topic>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <title>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                        </title>
                        <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
                     </topic>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            </topic>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
   </xsl:template>
```

I'm getting output as:

```
<topic id="topic_">
   <title> </title>
</topic>
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Taking</title>
   <body>
      <p>Your records.</p>
   </body>
   <topic id="topic_2">
      <title>Blood Pressure?</title>
      <body>
         <p>mmm.</p>
      </body>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

Expected output would be:

```
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Taking</title>
   <body>
      <p>Your records.</p>
   </body>
   <topic id="topic_2">
      <title>Blood Pressure?</title>
      <body>
         <p>mmm.</p>
      </body>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

Due to the unwanted element of the `<p> </p>`. I'm getting the error in the output. How we can ignore that particular instance by using that Body template. Please suggest me the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't explained the criteria deciding when/why to ignore an element, if you don't want to process the white-space only elements then using `xsl:for-each-group select="*[normalize-space()]"` might suffice.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your XSLT failed is a weird detail in the way how `for-each-group` operates (at least in *Saxon* engine).

If the source content does not start with the element given in `group-starting-with`, then the whole content before creates the first *false* output group.

To circumvent this issue, you have to:

- Read the first node in the current output group.
- Perform further operation only if its name is as expected.

Below you have a working solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
        <xsl:variable name="tag1" select="current-group()[1]"/>
        <xsl:if test="$tag1/name() = 'h1'">
          <topic id="topic_1">
            <title><xsl:value-of select="$tag1"/></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[2]"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="h2">
              <xsl:variable name="tag1" select="current-group()[1]"/>
              <xsl:if test="$tag1/name() = 'h2'">
                <topic id="topic_2">
                  <title><xsl:value-of select="$tag1"/></title>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[name()='p']"/>
                </topic>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </topic>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <body>
      <xsl:sequence select="."/>    
    </body>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that I added `copy` for `Body` element.
Otherwise, if your source contained more than 1 `h1` element, you would get improperly formatted output
(at the 1st level XML must contain **only 1** root tag).